# WinSCP commandline: Hostkey not found in cache error

Tags: ssh, scripting, public-key, winscp

I am trying to connect to Unix server from WinSCP commandline for the first time.

It closes with the the following error:

> The server's host key was not found in the cache. You have no guarantee that the
>    server is the computer you think it is.
>
> The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
>   ssh-rsa 1024 42:9e:c7:f4:7f:8b:50:10:6a:06:04:b1:d4:f2:04:6d
>   If you trust this host, **press Yes**. To connect without adding host key to the cac
>   he, **press No.** To abandon the connection **press Cancel**.

In the WinSCP commandline, it does not ask for any input (Yes or No). It closes with *Authentication failed*. If I connect through the WinSCP tool, I'll get the same error. However, I'll be able to press YES.

I also know that If I add `-hostkey` switch in the command line, I'll be able to connect. But, I don't want pass hostkey in my batch script as I will be connecting to various servers. So, my requirement is to pass "YES" input from the commandline in case of this error. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

A host key fingerprint verification is a crucial step in securing your SSH connection. Even if you are using a set of sessions with your script, it does not excuse you. The fingerprint should be part of a set of information you have for each of the sessions (in addition to a hostname, an username and a password).

Skipping the fingerprint verification means that you lose any security and there's no point using an SSH/SFTP anymore.

Anyway, if you do not care about a security, you can use the [`-hostkey=*` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open#hostkey) to unconditionally accept any host key.

Further references:

- [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)
- [Verifying the host key](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_verifying_the_host_key)

Comment: hi @Martin, this is not working for me. call C:\Progra~2\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe /console -timeout="120" /command "option batch continue" "option confirm off" "open sftp://%userin%:%pasw%@host -hostkey="*"" "get /home/*.*"

Comment: Your command conflicts with Markdown syntax, so I cannot see it literally. But I assume that original was `"open sftp://%userin%:%pasw%@host -hostkey="*""`. That's wrong, either use `"open sftp://%userin%:%pasw%@host -hostkey=""*"""` or avoid quotes around `*`: `"open sftp://%userin%:%pasw%@host -hostkey=*"` See [command-line syntax](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#syntax).

Comment: Also `-timeout="120"` specified as command-line parameter does not apply to session opened using scripting commands. You have to combine it with `open` command: `"open sftp://%userin%:%pasw%@host -hostkey=* -timeout=120"`